# Having difficulty registering AMI on ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2

So I have created an AMI bundle, and have uploaded it to a S3 bucket.  I then tried to run ec2-register and I was told

```
Client.InvalidManifest: HTTP 404 (Not Found) response for URL     
http://s3.amazonaws.com:80/opscode-public-amis/ubuntu-natty-11.04-i386-client1.manifest.xml: 
check your manifest path is correct and in the correct region.
```

I then went to my 3s bucket, and right clicked on the manifest file and selected "Make Public"  But that didn't seem to have any effect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your url looks like it is missing the correct region. It should look something like https://s3-region.amazonaws.com/bucketname/file.xml

When viewing the file in your S3 bucket in AWS you should see the link in its properties.